# draw rectangles on map with defined measures

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mesh, google-maps-api-2

I would like to draw mesh over a map by defining the measurement by km. For example drawing rectangles with length of 10 km and height of 12 km. I would like to be able to define such measurements and then the screen would be divided with those mesh (rectangles) as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voRcT.png).
Currently, I am getting the coordinates of the screen (NorthE, NorthW, SouthE, SouthW) and divided it by a number and looping inside it so I can draw rectangles with googlemaps API with those coordinates. 
My question is, can I do the same but instead of defining a number to divide the longitude and latitude, can I define the size (by km or m) for the height and length for my rectangles so I can have the same result as below (dividing the screen with rectangles with a defined size)
My code is as below:

```
 function drawRectanglezoom(map,zoom) {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var longeur = []
  var largeur = []
  var zoomy = zoom /2
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var tileWidth = (northEast.lng() - southWest.lng()) / zoom;
  var tileHeight = (northEast.lat() - southWest.lat()) / zoomy;
  for (var x = 0; x <= zoom; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= zoom; y++) {
      var a = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x))
      var b = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * (x+1)))
      var c = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x))
      var d = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * (y+1)),southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x))
      distancelongeur = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (a, b);
      distancehauteur = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (c, d);
      largeur.push(distancehauteur)
      longeur.push(distancelongeur)
      // console.log(' distance entre A et B', distancelongeur)
      // console.log('hauteur distance entre C et D', distancehauteur)
      var areaBounds = {
          north: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * (y+1)),
          south: southWest.lat() + (tileHeight * y),
          east: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * (x+1)),
          west: southWest.lng() + (tileWidth * x)
        };

     var area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        map: map,
        bounds: areaBounds

      });
      area.setMap(map)
      list.push(area)
    }

  }

  }
```

The response does not necessarily have to be with googlemaps, if I can do so with queries (MySQL) or other ways, it would really resolve my issue.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
img = matplotlib.image.imread("./kite_logo.png")
figure, ax = pyplot.subplots(1)
rect = patches.Rectangle((125,100),50,25, edgecolor='r', facecolor="none")
ax.imshow(img)
```

Displays an image

```
ax.add_patch(rect)
```

Add rectangle to image